# Using the value of a hidden field within a PHP recordset.

Tags: php, recordset

I have a form :

```
<form method="POST">
<input name="imagekey" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row_images['key']; ?>">
</form>
```

This returns an integer (the unique key for a recordset 'images'). I'm trying to create a second recordset that includes every value of 'images' with a greater key than the one specified in the hidden value.  ie if the hidden value is 5, then the second recordset will include everything with a key 6 and above.

I'm using Dreamweaver to create this, and the recordset code for this is:

```
SELECT *
FROM images
WHERE `key` > colname
ORDER BY `key` ASC
```

with colname being:

```
$colname_images2 = "-1";
if (isset($_POST['imagekey'])) {
  $colname_images2 = $_POST['imagekey'];
```

At the moment, I'm still getting the whole recordset including the hiddenvalue in my second recordset. Am I missing something obvious?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can minus directly you `POST` value

```
if (isset($_POST['imagekey'])) 
{
    $colname_images2 = $_POST['imagekey'] - 1;
}
```

The way you did you were setting for variable `$colname_images2 = "-1"` and then you were overwriting it with `$_POST['imagekey']`

in other hands you can set directly in your form the desired second value

```
<form method="POST">
    <input name="imagekey" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row_images['key']; ?>">
    <input name="imagekey2" type="hidden" value="<?php echo ($row_images['key'] - 1); ?>">
</form>
```

and now assign to a variable

```
$colname_images2 = $_POST['imagekey2'];
```

Comment: I replaced my if statement within $colname with yours and still the same result sadly :-(